# No-collide-Chain Wrecking Ball

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

So, I am having this problem with a wrecking ball simulation from a Youtube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nHVYYMG3QVY

Because the Chain under the Top chain is Not Colliding from the Chain Over,

Looks like I need help.

Data:
/Top Chain Collision(?): Mesh
/Top Dynamic Or Animated?: None
/Bottom Chain Collision(?): Mesh
/Bottom Chain Dynamic or Animated?: Dynamic

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7307/599

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found out the problem, It was too big so I needed to scale it down.